# (SOLVED) Why doesn't the Ruby Git gem see my variables?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-git

I'm building a simple utility for cloning down git repositories of other ruby programs my company has built, then install and configure them.

So, I'm very new to Ruby, so I apologize if this is a super noob question.

But I have a class that handles creating the directories it needs and cloning the repo, but it's returning this error when I run the code, and I don't know why...

This is the error:

```
Cloning the requested Git Repository now!
-----------------------------------------
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/git-1.12.0/lib/git/lib.rb:1125:in `command': git "-c" "core.quotePath=true" 
"-c" "color.ui=false" clone "--" "" "{:path=>\\"\\", :bare=>true}"  2>&1:fatal: The empty string is not a valid path (Git::GitExecuteError)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/git-1.12.0/lib/git/lib.rb:116:in `clone'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/git-1.12.0/lib/git/base.rb:21:in `clone'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/git-1.12.0/lib/git.rb:176:in `clone'
        from C:/Users/conno/OneDrive/Desktop/Ruby Installer/Pixelated-Ruby-Installer/classes/Gitclone.rb:43:in `clone'
        from ./starter.rb:48:in `<main>'
```

This is my code (again, remember I am very new. So literally any and all advice is helpful):

```
#!/bin/ruby
# class declaration
class Gitclone
    require "fileutils"
    require "git"
    require "rubygems"
    # attribute reader so other classes/methods can read the vars in this class
    attr_reader :giturl, :destpa

    # init class method to set instance variables for giturl and destination path
    def initialize(giturl, destpa)
        @giturl = giturl
        @destpa = destpa
    end
    
    # class method to create directories and clone git repositories
    def self.clone
    # I don't think this needs to be here. It was added for the sake of seeing if it would fix the issue
        giturl = @giturl
        destpa = @destpa
    # see last comment about the above 2 lines
        puts "Creating directories!"
        21.times {
            print "-"
        }
        puts ""
        sleep(2)
        # right now, this is hardcoded. I should probably make it it's own method we can call...
        # it creates new directories
        FileUtils.mkdir_p "/etc/pixelated/ruby/bin"
        puts "We have created the /etc/pixelated/ruby/bin directory!"
        54.times {
            print "-"
        }
        puts ""
        sleep(2)
        puts "Cloning the requested Git Repository now!"
        41.times {
            print "-"
        }
        puts ""
        sleep(2)
        # this bit here simply uses the Git gem to clone the repository URL stored in the 'giturl' instance variable to the path stored in the 'destpa' instance variable
        git = Git.clone("#{giturl}", path: "#{destpa}", bare: true)

        # notify the user if the repository was cloned successfuly
        if Dir.exist?("/etc/pixelated/ruby/bin/$softtype")
            then 
                puts "Successfully Cloned the Repo!"
                puts ""
            else
                puts "ERROR! Repo was not cloned! Did you give us the right link?"
                puts ""
        end
    end
end
```

I did declare the variables that I'm using, yet it apparently thinks they haven't?

I am almost certain that this is my noob brain using variable wrong...

Can someone offer me some guidance please?

EDIT: I may have answered my own question. I realized I'm booted into my Windows OS, not Arch Linux, and my code is using Linux paths, not Windows paths. Gonna put it up on one of my ubuntu servers and see if it works there.

Comment: Tip: It's convention to have the `require` statements at the top of the file, outside of any class definitions, etc.

Comment: Tip: `puts "-" * 41` That's also a whole lot of sleeping on the job.

Comment: All of my sleeping is actually just me doing it so that text doesn't whizz by my screen. I'll remove it long before I'm done. Text going up super fast makes my eyes bug out. Always has, never really known why.

However! 

I did end up fixing my own problem by switching to linux. I should mark this closed or something. As soon as I figure out how...

Comment: Your issue is actually related to the fact that you are conflating instance methods (and instance variables) with class instance methods (and class instance variables). If you were to change `def self.clone` to just `def clone` and then call as `g = Gitclone.new(some_giturl, some_destpa); g.clone` then everything *should* execute accordingly. Right now `@giturl` and `@destpa` are instance variables with reader instance methods (getter) but you are trying to access them in the class instance method `clone`. These variables are therefor not set and not accessible and thus your issue.

Comment: I did also figure that out myself by switching from writing in Vim to writing in RubyMine. The IDE has really helped me with the learning process by being automatically configured to check syntax and stuff properly. Which I clearly didn't set up properly in Vim

PS: could someone tell me how to close this post please? The issue has been resolved!